# There is at least one case were a null primary key is needed. How to treat this particular case?

Tags: database, primary-key

I've a table SCHOOL_PARENT and a table SCHOOL_CHILD. The SCHOOL_CHILD table contains an id for the child and an id for the parent, that togheter forms the primary key. This is because a child can have two parents (mom and father, therefore 2 rows).

Exists then the case of a child without any parents. But I can't insert this row because the table SCHOOL_CHILD doesn't accept a NULL parent, being part of the primary key. How to solve this problem?

Comment: If you already have on SCHOOL_CHILD a id of the child. Why don't you have 2 simple foreign keys to SCHOOL_PARENT that can be null?

Comment: Because I would have a duplicate in child_id. child_id 1 for mom and child_id 1 for dad

Comment: Make two tables: SCHOOL_CHILD_PARENT and SCHOOL_CHILD. Modelling the child in your current table alone wouldn't make sense because any attributes of the child would have to be duplicated - once for each parent. No key ever needs to include nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've understood the question properly, but I think your data model is something like:

```
Table: Parent
------------
ParentID (PK)
Name
....

Table: Child
------------
ChildID (PK)
Name
....

Table: Parent_Child
----------------
ParentID (PK)
ChildID (PK)
```

There is a many-to-many relationship between children and parents; you typically model this in a "bridging" table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Table: SCHOOL_PARENT 
------------
ParentID (PK)
Name
....

Table: SCHOOL_CHILD
------------
ChildID (PK)
MotherID (FK)
FatherID (FK)
Name
....
```

FatherID ant MotherID can be null.